# Nuget Pack with -IncludeReferencedProjects includes itself

Tags: nuget

My nuget build script,

```
  <BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);TargetPath=$(OutDir)$(AssemblyName)$(TargetExt)" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) $(PackageOutputSwitch) -IncludeReferencedProjects  -verbosity detailed</BuildCommand>
```

is for some of my projects including the project itself as a dependency. I have no idea why.

outputted nuget spec in the nupkg

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Ascend.Data.ServiceBus</id>
    <version>1.0.0-pre-2014052105</version>
    <title>Ascend.Data.ServiceBus</title>
    <authors>Ascend Aps</authors>
    <owners>Ascend Aps</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <copyright>Copyright 2014</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="AzureWebRole.MessageProcessor.Core" version="1.0.0-CI00028" />
      <dependency id="AzureWebRole.MessageProcessor.ServiceBus" version="1.0.0-CI00028" />
      <dependency id="S-Innovations.Azure.TableStorageRepository" version="1.0.0-CI00020" />
      <dependency id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" />
      <dependency id="Ascend.Data.ServiceBus" version="1.0.0-pre-2014052105" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance, your solution has a circular dependency? If possible, can you please share a simplified repro project and report an issue on http://nuget.codeplex.com? Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem by adding nuspec files to the projects with the id hard coded. Else it swapped in wrong ids when looking for dependencies. This solution is okay with me.